how to display an Focus rectangle in webview
I am building an webapp for android tv , to control the interface ( using D-pad ) i am trying display an rectangle on a focusable element in an WebView like this
.
I got this result from :

<WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"

        android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"
        android:focusable="true"  // getting dotted line

       />

 webView.apply {
            setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient())
            getSettings().cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
            getSettings().mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE;
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

            settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
            settings.blockNetworkImage = false
            isFocusable = true
            isFocusableInTouchMode = true


        }

